# Splash Screen carregando com aplicação

Tags: java, swing, thread

Minha aplicação, ao iniciar, faz a primeira pesquisa no banco de dados. Como eu utilizo o `Hibernate`, esta primeira conexão é um pouco mais demorada pois monta todo o mapeamento do banco. Eu estou pensando em adicionar um Splash Screen no início, para que o usuário não pense que a aplicação travou ou não esta carregando, mas pelos exemplos que vi, devo informar uma quantidade de tempo para a `Thread` carregar. Só que o tempo de carregamento do sistema varia conforme as configurações do micro, se o sistema já foi aberto na máquina ou se ainda esta em memória.

Minha dúvida é saber se consigo fazer o tempo de vida do Splash demorar o tempo de carregamento do meu sistema.

Segue abaixo exemplo de como eu inicio o meu sistema e como gero o meu Splash.

**Splash.java**

```
....

/**
*
*   @author desenvolvimento
*/
public class Splash extends JWindow {

AbsoluteLayout absoluto;
AbsoluteConstraints absimagem, absbarra;
ImageIcon image;
JLabel jLabel;
JProgressBar barra;

public Splash() {

    absoluto = new AbsoluteLayout();
    absimagem = new AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0);
    absbarra = new AbsoluteConstraints(0, 284);
    jLabel = new JLabel();
    image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/imagem/Logo.png"));
    jLabel.setIcon(image);
    barra = new JProgressBar();
    barra.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(285, 10));
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(absoluto);
    this.getContentPane().add(jLabel, absimagem);
    this.getContentPane().add(barra, absbarra);
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);

    new Thread() {

        public void run() {

            int i = 0;
            while (i < 101) {
                barra.setValue(i);
                i++;
                try {

                    sleep(150);

                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Splash.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }

            TelaLogin x = new TelaLogin();
            x.setVisible(true);

        }

    }.start();
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}

}
```

**Principal.java**

```
public class Agil {


public static void main(String[] args) {
  TelaLogin telaLogin = new TelaLogin();
    telaLogin.validate();
    telaLogin.pack();
    telaLogin.setVisible(false);
   }
}
```

**TelaLogin.java**

```
public class TelaLogin extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form TelaLogin
 */
public TelaLogin() {
    initComponents();

   new Splash();

    EmitenteDAO emitentedao = new EmitenteDAO();
    String nomeFantasia = emitentedao.getEmitente();
    LbEmpresaLogin.setText(nomeFantasia);

    LeituraXmlConfig config = new LeituraXmlConfig();

    if (config.getValidaConfig().equals("0")) {

        //Inicia configuração
    } else if (config.getValidaConfig().equals("1")) {

    }


    URL url = this.getClass().getResource("imagem/icon_32.png");
    Image iconeTitulo = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);    
    this.setIconImage(iconeTitulo);

    TxUsuarioLogin.setDocument(new EntradaUpperCase());

}

Session session = Session.getSession();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

 ........
```

Comment: Creio que você pode tirar da thread o preenchimento automático da barra, e a cada evento de carregamento, ele colocar uma porcentagem na barra.

Comment: Ok, tem um exemplo onde posso me basear?

Comment: Dê uma pesquisada sobre os métodos `wait()` e `notify()`;

Comment: Você não está usando os recursos corretos para trabalhar múltiplas threads no Swing. Dê uma lida sobre como usar o [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa seria usar a classe [**`SplashScreen`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html), com ela o próprio java se encarrega de exibir e fechar a splash assim que uma janela `awt/swing` for aberta.

Como exemplo segue o código que peguei do próprio [tutorial do Netbeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Splash_Screen_Beginner_Tutorial) e adaptei:

```
public class CustomSplashScreen {

    private static SplashScreen mySplash;
    private static Graphics2D splashGraphics;
    private static Rectangle2D.Double splashProgressArea;

    public static void splashInit() {

        mySplash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();

        if (mySplash != null) {
            //pega as dimensoes da imagem que será usada no splashscreen
            // para que a barra fique proporcional
            Dimension ssDim = mySplash.getSize();
            int height = ssDim.height;
            int width = ssDim.width;
            //desenha a área da barra de progresso, você pode alterar as dimensoes pra testar a que mais gostar
            //  os parametros representam posição horizontal  e vertical (em relação a imagem), altura e largura, respectivamente
            splashProgressArea = new Rectangle2D.Double(1.0, height * 0.87, width, height * 0.08);
            //exibe a imagem do splash centralizada na tela
            splashGraphics = mySplash.createGraphics();
            //inicia a barra de progresso(pode ser removido)
            splashProgress(0);
        }
    }

    public static void splashProgress(int pct) {
        if (mySplash != null && mySplash.isVisible()) {
            
            //preenche a area da barra de progresso com a cor informada
            splashGraphics.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            splashGraphics.fill(splashProgressArea);
            
            //colore bordas na barra de progresso(opcional)
            splashGraphics.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
            splashGraphics.draw(splashProgressArea);
            
            //pega o menor valor das coordenadas(horizontal  X e vertical Y) da barra 
            //será usado para o carregamento(não alterar daqui em diante)
            int x = (int) splashProgressArea.getMinX();
            int y = (int) splashProgressArea.getMinY();
            int wid = (int) splashProgressArea.getWidth();
            int hgt = (int) splashProgressArea.getHeight();
            
            //valor usado para o carregamento da barra
            int doneWidth = Math.round(pct * wid / 100.f);
            doneWidth = Math.max(0, Math.min(doneWidth, wid - 1));
            
            //aqui  é que vai preenchendo o carregamento da barra de acordo com o valor
            //passado em pct    
            splashGraphics.setPaint(Color.GREEN);
            splashGraphics.fillRect(x, y + 1, doneWidth, hgt - 1);
            mySplash.update();
        }
    }
}
```

Mas antes de usar a classe, é importante adicionar uma imagem no seu projeto e a referência no `manifest.mf`. Se estiver usando `Netbeans`, o arquivo estará mais ou menos assim:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
```

Altere desta forma:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
SplashScreen-Image: <caminho da imagem>
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
```

onde `caminho da imagem` deve ser o path de onde a imagem se encontra no seu projeto. Como exemplo, veja meu projeto teste:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo, o endereço da imagem vai ficar assim:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
SplashScreen-Image: splashdemo/splash.png
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
```

Depois, para chamar, basta fazer assim no seu `main`

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    CustomSplashScreen.splashInit();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        CustomSplashScreen.splashProgress(i * 20);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

O `for` irá incrementar um valor que será passado para referência do progresso, e `(i*20)` é apenas uma personalização da forma como a barra vai se incrementar no progresso, você pode personalizar aqui da forma que quiser.

**Observação:** é possível também testar via execução do próprio netbeans, indo nas Propriedades e adicionando a linha `-splash:src/splashdemo/splash.png` em VM Options:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim não é necessário ficar gerando o jar toda hora para testar.

Há mais exemplos em https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html

---

## Limitações

Conforme relatado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117187/28595), o progresso não é sincronizado com o carregamento da Thread, mas o splash é fechado assim que uma janela do `awt/swing` se torna visível.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve iniciar a Thread Splash, que irá aparecer na sua tela imediatamente ao início da aplicação, e deixa a segunda Thread carregando as paradas do banco, ao término do carregamento do Hibernate, antes dela chamar a tela da aplicação, você mata a primeira thread e aí vem a tela da aplicação. Assim ele ficará "calibrado" para qualquer tipo de hardware.

Answer (score 0):

A Splash Screen foi montada da seguinte forma:

A classe principal chama um JFrame que possui uma imagem que fica visualmente no centro da tela até que a aplicação faça o primeiro mapeamento do banco e monte a comunicação a tela fica visível.

principal.java

```
SplashPrincipal sc = new SplashPrincipal();
    sc.setVisible(true);
    sc.setSize(535, 235);


    TelaLogin telaLogin = new TelaLogin();
    telaLogin.validate();
    telaLogin.pack();
    telaLogin.setVisible(true);

    sc.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Já pensou em usar a classe SplashScreen nativa do java? ela já trata de exibir para você.

Comment: nunca li sobre o assunto, vou procurar por informações e ver se consigo melhorar a função. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Veja o código nessa pergunta. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115954/exibir-splashscreen-com-progresso-enquanto-jframe-%C3%A9-carregado?noredirect=1#comment241883_115954