# Exibir SplashScreen com progresso enquanto JFrame é carregado

Tags: java, swing, thread

Tenho um aplicativo feito em [swing](/questions/tagged/swing), e estou tentando adicionar uma `SplashScreen` nele. Consegui fazer a classe `SplashScreen` funcionar normalmente, mas não estou conseguindo sincronizar o carregamento do JFrame no `invokeLater` com o carregamento da `splashScreen`.

Segue o código da `splashScreen` que estou usando:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.SplashScreen;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class GerOficioSplashScreen {

    private static SplashScreen mySplash;
    private static Graphics2D splashGraphics;
    private static Rectangle2D.Double splashProgressArea;

    public static void splashInit() {

        mySplash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();

        if (mySplash != null) {

            Dimension ssDim = mySplash.getSize();
            int height = ssDim.height;
            int width = ssDim.width;

            splashProgressArea = new Rectangle2D.Double(1., height * .87, width, height * 0.08);

            splashGraphics = mySplash.createGraphics();
            splashProgress(0);
        }
    }

    public static void splashProgress(int pct) {
        if (mySplash != null && mySplash.isVisible()) {

            splashGraphics.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            splashGraphics.fill(splashProgressArea);

            splashGraphics.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
            splashGraphics.draw(splashProgressArea);

            int x = (int) splashProgressArea.getMinX();
            int y = (int) splashProgressArea.getMinY();
            int wid = (int) splashProgressArea.getWidth();
            int hgt = (int) splashProgressArea.getHeight();

            int doneWidth = Math.round(pct * wid / 100.f);
            doneWidth = Math.max(0, Math.min(doneWidth, wid - 1));

            splashGraphics.setPaint(Color.GREEN);
            splashGraphics.fillRect(x, y + 1, doneWidth, hgt - 1);

            mySplash.update();
        }
    }
}
```

A chamada dele no `main` da minha tela em `JFrame` está assim:

```
   public static void main(String args[]) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GerOficioSplashScreen.splashInit();

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    GerOficioSplashScreen.splashProgress(i * 20);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    Propriedade p = new Propriedade();
                    for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                        if ((p.getLookAndFeel()).equalsIgnoreCase(info.getName())) {
                            javax.swing.UIManager.put("control", new Color(230, 230, 230));
                            javax.swing.UIManager.put("background", new Color(0, 230, 230));
                            javax.swing.UIManager.put("Table.showGrid", true);
                            javax.swing.UIManager.put("Table.alternateRowColor", new Color(232, 232, 232));
                            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    ListaDeOficiosUI_unificada a = new ListaDeOficiosUI_unificada();
                    a.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    a.setVisible(true);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException | IOException ex) {
                    PrintMessageUI.exibirError(null, "Erro ao abrir o programa.\n" + ex.getMessage());
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

O problema é fazer com que a `SplashScreen` carregue conforme a renderização da tela no `invokeLater`, ela se fecha antes de terminar de carregar o progresso, e a tela do `JFrame` se abre.

Como faço pra sincronizar a renderização do `JFrame` iniciado no `invokeLater` com a barra de progresso da `splashScreen`?

Comment: +1 porque eu não conhecia esse `SplashScreen`, [sempre usei `JDialog` para isto](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b9tOM.png).

Comment: @renan eu também não, mas [esse tutorial](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Splash_Screen_Beginner_Tutorial) do netbeans me salvou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como não encontrei uma forma de sincronizar corretamente a barra de progresso de acordo com o carregamento do meu `JFrame` dentro da [event-dispatch-thread](/questions/tagged/event-dispatch-thread) (EDT), acabei por carregar a [**`SplashScreen`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) em uma `Thread`paralela ao EDT. Fiz alguns testes pra obter a média de tempo que a aplicação leva pra carregar e adaptei esse tempo na barra de progresso da `SplashScreen` e o resto me baseei na documentação:

> The splash screen window is closed automatically as soon as the first
>   window is displayed by Swing/AWT (may be also closed manually using
>   the Java API, see below).

Ou seja, assim que o `JFrame` estiver renderizado e ficar visível, o próprio java fecha o `SplashScreen` e em seguida, finaliza sua Thread.

Não foi a melhor solução, pois o `JFrame` pode aparecer mesmo que a barra não esteja completa, mas atendeu pontualmente ao meu problema.

O código da pergunta não foi alterado.