# Minha JLabel não aparece

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Ja usei trocentos comandos para fazer essa Label aparecer, mas não consigo, nesse objeto estou usando paint e `ActionPerformed`, mas nenhum drawing esta sobrepondo essa label e mesmo assim ela não aparece, alguém tem idéia do por que?

```
package scenes;

import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Title extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    JLabel press_enter = new JLabel("Pressione ENTER para começar", JLabel.CENTER);
    Font font = new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 32);
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    private BufferedImage city1;
    private BufferedImage city2;
    private BufferedImage tipography;
    private int phase = 1;
    private int city1_h = 1;
    private int city1_h_final = 5;
    private int city2_h = 1;
    private int city2_h_final = 5;
    private int city1_y = 220;
    private int city1_y_final = 0;
    private int city2_y = 218;
    private int city2_y_final = 0;
    private int bloco1 = 0;
    private int bloco2 = 0;
    private boolean loaded = false;
    private float alpha = 1.0f;

    public Title(){

        setSize( 800, 600 );
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        Timer t = new Timer(20, this);
        t.start();
        press_enter.setAlignmentX(0);
        press_enter.setAlignmentY(0);
        press_enter.setBounds(130, 280, 200, 60);
        press_enter.setVisible(true);
        press_enter.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        add(press_enter);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (loaded == false) {
            try {
                tipography = ImageIO.read(new File("images/scene/tipo.png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("imagem não encontrada!");
            }
            try {
                city1 = ImageIO.read(new File("images/scene/logo2.png"));
                city1_h_final = city1.getHeight();
                city1_h_final = city1_h_final - (city1_h_final * 2);
                city1_y = 150 + (tipography.getHeight()/2);
                city1_y_final = 148;
                bloco1 = 150 + (tipography.getHeight()/2);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("imagem não encontrada!");
            }
            try {
                city2 = ImageIO.read(new File("images/scene/logo2.png"));
                city2_h_final = city2.getHeight();
                city2_y = 150 + (tipography.getHeight()/2) - 2;
                city2_y_final = 150 + (tipography.getHeight()/2) * 2;
                bloco2 = 150 + (tipography.getHeight()/2) - 2;
                loaded = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("imagem não encontrada!");
            }
        }
        Graphics2D city1_2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        Graphics2D city2_2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        Graphics2D tipography_2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        city1_2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha));
        tipography_2d.drawImage(tipography, (800/2) - (tipography.getWidth()/2), 150, tipography.getWidth(), tipography.getHeight(), null);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect((800/2) - (city1.getWidth()/2), bloco1, city1.getWidth(), city1_h_final);
        g.fillRect((800/2) - (city1.getWidth()/2), bloco2, city1.getWidth(), city2_h_final);
        city1_2d.drawImage(city1, (800/2) - (city1.getWidth()/2), city1_y, city1.getWidth(), city1_h, null);
        city2_2d.drawImage(city2, (800/2) - (city2.getWidth()/2), city2_y, city2.getWidth(), city2_h, null);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (phase == 1){
            if (city1_h > city1_h_final)
                city1_h -= 1;
            else if (city1_h == city1_h_final)
                phase = 2;
            if (city2_h < city2_h_final)
                city2_h += 1;

            repaint();
        } else if (phase == 2) {
            if (city1_y > city1_y_final){
                city1_y -= 1;
                bloco1 -= 1;
            }
            if (city2_y < city2_y_final){
                city2_y += 1;
                bloco2 += 1;
                add(press_enter);
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }   
}
```

---

```
package engine;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Display extends JFrame {

    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    public Display(){
        setTitle("BlackJack");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(800,600);
        setResizable(false);
        this.setLocation(dim.width/2-this.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-this.getSize().height/2);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,0,0));
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Title extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    JLabel press_enter = new JLabel("Pressione ENTER para começar", JLabel.CENTER);
    Font font = new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 32);

    public Title(){

        setVisible(true);
        setLocation (0,0);
        setSize( 800, 600 );
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        Timer t = new Timer(20, this);
        //t.start();
        press_enter.setAlignmentX(0);
        press_enter.setAlignmentY(0);
        //press_enter.setFont(font);
        press_enter.setBounds(130, 280, 200, 60);
        press_enter.setVisible(true);
        press_enter.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        add(press_enter);

    }
```

https://github.com/Forsaiken/BlackJack

Comment: Estou votando o fechamento desta pergunta pois o problema descrito pelo autor já foi solucionado na resposta, e o mesmo ou não está sabendo demonstrar o real problema ou não se trata de algo reproduzivel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A causa do `JLabel` não ser exibida está exatamente neste trecho abaixo da classe `Title`:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
```

Consegue reparar algo errado ai? Você sobrescreve erroneamente o método `paint()`, mas invoca o `paintComponent()`. Acredito que tenha sido um erro de digitação, pois trocando a assinatura do método para `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` o label é exibido normalmente.

Porém, mesmo assim sugiro que leia os links que deixarei abaixo para entender porque isso ocorreu e como iniciar corretamente uma aplicação swing:

- [O que é Event-Dispatching Thread (EDT) em interfaces gráficas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115168/28595)
- [Por que o método main deve despachar a criação da GUI para a EDT?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/28595)
- [Wiki sobre a Event-Dispatch-Thread(ou EDT)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/event-dispatch-thread/info)
- [Qual a diferença entre usar SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable) e EventQueue.invokeLater(Runnable) ao invocar uma janela?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176713/28595)

Se o objetivo é fazer uma splash screen, também deixarei abaixo um exemplo respondido aqui mesmo no site, da forma que você está fazendo não está correto:

- [Exemplo de uso da classe SplashScreen](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117190/28595) e
- [suas possíveis limitações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117187/28595)

Comment: Eu ja coloquei o JPanel em um JFrame, isso é apenas um objeto, a função main não esta nela e a função main ja adiciona o painel no frame. Os drawings que usei no paint dessa classe aparecem normalmente, então o painel esta no frame.

Comment: @Forsaiken pra mim funcionou normalmente, basta executar o código da resposta.

Comment: Coloquei na pergunta os códigos do JFrame e do Main a aplicação continua a ignorar o JLabel

Comment: @Forsaiken veja a edição da resposta, se quiser ainda sim algo mais especifico, edite a pergunta e forneça mais detalhes do problema e também acesse o link que segue e forneça um **[mcve]** do seu código.

Comment: segue o repositório desse projeto: https://github.com/Forsaiken/BlackJack Eu usei o thread.sleep para segurar a animação da intro que dura 7 segundos para dai então passar para o Title. Ainda estou aprendendo essa parte de animação, mas darei uma lida, a parte de controle dos threads eu ainda não aprendi.

Comment: @Forsaiken a solução está na resposta, basta da uma lida. O que você está fazendo de intro se chama SPLASH SCREEN, e tambem tem na minha resposta. Se não era isso que queria, então sua pergunta não está clara.

Comment: Eu li, você pediu para remover o thread.sleep, eu removi, a label continua a não aparecer. O Invokelater não entendi bem sua função, mas quando insiro ele na main, ele faz a intro ficar bugada e não mostra os drawing da mesma. eu removi o setvisible e setlocation do JPanel e continua a mesma. O setsize do frame ja esta no display.java. A actionperfomed eu não inseri na pergunta pois achei desnecessario, pois a label não vai nela, a actionperfomed esta fazendo auxilio na animação da Title. De qualquer modo Label continua não aparecendo no painel.

Comment: @Forsaiken olha o print da pergunta. o label está no topo!

Comment: Sim compreendo @Articuno, o seu código sendo feito de um projeto zerado ele funciona, pois ele cria normalmente a Label, no meu projeto e nessa classe ele não é criado, mesmo estando totalmente correto. Eu editei a pergunta e coloquei todo o código que tem na class Title. O Class Title esta rodando normalmente mas a label não aparece de forma alguma. A class Intro acho que nem é necessaria colocar, pois a mesma esta rodando normalmente. Eu preciso saber o que esta causando esse bug na JLabel para ela não aparecer.

Comment: @Forsaiken as imagens que você está adicionando estão sobrepondo o label, tente remover todas as imagens, executar o código e ver se o label é exibido. Depois readicione as imagens e execute e veja se o label some. Faça este teste ai.

Comment: @Forsaiken não há problema algum no seu projeto, apenas removendo o trecho que sugeri na resposta, apareceu aqui normalmente, portanto, estou votando para fechar sua pergunta porque não é possivel reproduzir o problema ou você não está sabendo demonstra-lo no site.

Comment: Removi todos os drawimages e testei e mesmo assim não aparece. Removi o timer (ActionPerformed) e paint, mesmo assim não aparece. Removi o thread.sleep e também não aparece. Se não há solução pode fechar, eu posso usar o paint pra desenhar a label e resolver o problema.

Comment: @Forsaiken encontrei a causa, foi um erro no seu método de desenho da classe Title, por favor, reveja a resposta e aplique as modificações sugeridas.

Comment: Finally, Muito Obrigado @Articuno, agora deu certo.