# Como fazer uma thread para esperar uma outra classe ser finalizada e continuar o código?

Tags: java, event-dispatch-thread

Bem como está descrito no código preciso de uma solução para dar um **pause** na `main` até que aguarde algum chamado para continuar o código da classe `main`. Sei que isso se resolve com `thread`, mas até o momento não achei a forma de usa-lo para isso. Também acho que tem haver com o **EDT**, mas não sei muito sobre `thread`, então não consigo faze-lo.

---

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame{

    public Main(){
        setSize(800,600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main frame = new Main();
        Painel painel = new Painel();
        painel.setVisible(true);

        frame.add(painel);

        // Aguardar comando do Painel e continuar o código seguinte:

        System.out.println("OK");
        frame.remove(painel);

    }

}
```

---

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Painel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    JButton button = new JButton("Prosseguir main");

    public Painel(){
        button.setVisible(true);
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==button) {
            System.out.println("Escrever agora o OK no console e remover painel pela Main");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, forneça um **[mcve]** para que seja possível executar o código e testar o problema.

Comment: Editado articuno

Comment: Eu usaria algo como [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) ou uma `Lock` compartilhada. O main cria um objeto do tipo `CountDownLatch`, passa-o para o construtor do `Painel` e espera (`await`) pelo *countdown* executado no `ActionListener`. Além disso é boa prática (veja [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2017/por-que-o-método-main-deve-despachar-a-criação-da-gui-para-a-edt-em-uma-aplicação)) usar `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` para criar / exibir / modificar componentes AWT / Swing na EDT.

Comment: Gostei desse CountDownLatch, ele funcionou. Referente ao invokelater até o momento não entendi a exata função dele, li que tem algo haver com EventQueue, mas no momento pra mim é meio confuso, pois ainda não tive problemas na forma que estou escrevendo o código, cada painel tem seu actionListener e seu KeyListener e até o momento não estou fundindo 2 paineis na mesma janela e estou usando o remove(component) para remover o painel quando sair do mesmo.

Comment: A questão é só porque não deu problema não significa que esteja correto. Swing precisa ser dispachado, e para isso, você precisa iniciar a aplicação grafica dentro da EDT, através deste método. Pode não ter dado problema agora, mas ainda mais levando em consideração que você está começando a implementar threads, deveria mudar seu código para a forma correta, pois la na frente você vai ter um problema e pode não conseguir resolver justamente porque não quis dispachar a aplicação.

Comment: Esta alteração nem seria drástica no seu código, basta por tudo que está no seu método `main` dentro do `invokeLater()`. Eu já lhe indiquei um monte de bons links para ler [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/262195/28595), inclusive em um deles demonstra como dispachar para esta thread.

Comment: Sim, compreendo, mas o fato de eu não ter feito isso até o momento, foi por que o invokelater estava bugando os drawings, quando eu o colocava na main, depois eu tento aplica-la novamente e tento descobrir da onde vem o erro.