# ActionPerformed do JButton não abre o Frame antes de terminar todos os eventos

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

Tenho o seguinte problema:

Ao clicar no JButton quero abrir um Frame de espera que solicite ao usuário que espere alguns instantes e enquanto isso o programa vai processando os métodos de consulta que  demoram algum tempo.
Entretanto ao clicar no Jbutton ele executa todos os métodos no actionPerformed antes de abrir o Frame com a "tela de espera".

Aqui coloquei um exemplo genérico de código que  representa a forma que  estou implementando.

aqui a classe que monta a tela de Espera.

```
public class WaitSplash extends JFrame{
    public void showComponente() {
        JFrame frame =this;        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel();
        jLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/aguarde.gif")));
        panel.add(jLabel);
        panel.setBackground(new  Color( 221, 236, 239 ));
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(350, 121);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        centralizarComponente(frame);
    }
    public WaitSplash() throws HeadlessException {
        showComponente();
    }
    public void centralizarComponente(JFrame frame) {
        Dimension ds = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Dimension dw = frame.getSize();
        frame.setLocation((ds.width - dw.width) / 2, (ds.height - dw.height) / 2);
    }
    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean b) {
        super.setVisible(b);
    }
}
```

e aqui em baixo a classe com o Jbutton que deveria abrir a tela de espera enquanto executa o método .

```
public class NewClass {
  public void genericMethod(){
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Example");
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      JButton button =
      button= new JButton(new AbstractAction("Botao") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                WaitSplash wait;
                wait = new WaitSplash();
                wait.setVisible(true);
                wait.requestFocus();
                metodoQualquer();
                wait.dispose();
            }
        });
      panel.add(button);
      frame.add(panel);
      frame.setSize(300, 300);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    }

  public void metodoQualquer(){
      try {
      Thread.sleep(10000);
     } catch (Exception e) {}

  }
    public static void main(String s[]) {
     new NewClass().genericMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Você quer fazer uma [splashScreen](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117190/28595)?

Comment: uma splashScreen que dure enquanto os métodos do actionPerformed estejam rodando.

Comment: Tente a solução 2 dessa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120435/28595

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funcionou.
As modificações ficaram assim:

```
public class NewClass {

    public void genericMethod() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Example");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton button
                = button = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Botao") {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        ativarMetodos();
                    }
                });
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void metodoQualquer() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new NewClass1().genericMethod();
            }
        });

        //   new NewClass().genericMethod();
    }

    public void ativarMetodos() {
        SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                WaitSplash wait;
                wait = new WaitSplash();
                wait.setVisible(true);
                wait.requestFocus();
                metodoQualquer();
                wait.dispose();

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {

                super.done();
                try {
                    try {
                        get();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(NewClass1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(NewClass1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
    }
```